# How to limit number of iterations when looping through object in nunjucks

Tags: html, json, nunjucks

I have a js object like this:

```js
var data = [
    { src: "src1", name: "name 1" }, 
    { src: "src2", name: "name 2" }, 
    { src: "src3", name: "name 3" }
]
```

I am looping through it with Nunjucks:

```
{% for object in data %}
    {{object.src}}
{% endfor %}
```

But I want to ***limit the number of iterations to 2.***

How do I do that with Nunjucks?

I know there is a range option but I couldn't find how to use it in this case.

Comment: you can keep a counter and break from the loop once the counter reaches 2

Comment: Ah yes! Thx for the hint! This works:

{% set limit = 0 %}
    {% for object in data %}
        {% set limit = (limit+1) %}
        {% if limit <= 2 %}
            {{object.src}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could accomplish this a couple different ways:

#### A) Use `loop.index0` special variable ([Demo in Codepen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/embed/VwQyYKe?default-tab=js%2Cresult))

Inside a [for loop](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#for), you can use `loop.index0` instead `limit`-var

```
{% for obj in data %}
    {% if loop.index0 < 2 %}    
        {{obj.src}}: {{obj.name}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### B) Add Custom Filter ([Demo in Codepen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/embed/gOvoOVw?default-tab=js%2Cresult))

But more readable is add [custom filter](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api#custom-filters) `limit` and use it

```js
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

var data = [
    {src: "src1", name: "name 1"}, 
    {src: "src2", name: "name 2"}, 
    {src: "src3", name: "name 3"}
];

env.addFilter('limit', function(arr, limit) {
    return arr.slice(0, limit);
});

var res = nunjucks.renderString(`
    {% for obj in data | limit(2) %}
    {{obj.src}}: {{obj.name}}
    {% endfor %}`, 
    {data}
);

console.log(res);
```

#### C) Use native [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function ([Demo in Codepen](https://codepen.io/KyleMit/embed/KKQZKWW?default-tab=js%2Cresult))

```
{% for obj in data.slice(0, 2) %}
    {{obj.src}}: {{obj.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It seems that option C would be the easiest and the best answer. Unclear  to me why it is not the only option in this answer. Option B does the same as Option C, but is more complicated and I don't see any advantage. Option A has the disadvantage of not stopping the loop and might cause lots of empty output depending on the context. eg in my case extra blank lines in HTML. This is not a big deal, but slice() is surely the best and most efficient option.